# Disallow Bluethooth Discovery

Tags: bluetooth, debian

I run Debian and I do need Bluetooth to connect to my headset, but I don't want devices can see my laptop nor be able to connect to it.

I tried the following commands, but they just kill the Wifi; if I re-enable the wifi in my gnome-session, the bluetooth is discoverable.

```bsh
rfkill unblock 0
bluetoothctl discoverable no
rfkill block 0
```

I also tried the following command, but its effect isn't persistent and it doesn't work either.

```bsh
hciconfig hci0 noscan
```

I would like to handle it like I do with TCP-IP connections with `ufw`.

```bsh
deny incoming && allow outgoing
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Debian isn't supported here...  But I think it's easy to answer your question.  I don't think it's possible.  If you have your headphones in a crowded bus, *everyone* in your vicinity can see it.  Surely you've noticed this when you turn on bluetooth on your phone.  But you have to "pair" them in order for the two to connect.  So, what you're asking for doesn't seem (as far as I know) possible for any bluetooth device...so I don't expect Ubuntu/Debian to provide that for you.  Just my opinion...

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: @Ray Debian isnt supported here... ?? this is not just a "ubuntu forum"!

Comment: Yes, this is just an "ubuntu forum".  As you're new here, it's understandable that you were not aware of this.  I'm unsure why you think you know better?  Please see the comment before your's, which gives you a link explaining what is covered.

Comment: Sure pal, but Ubuntu inherits most of Debian, so why should you just be able to ask questions to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
sudo btmgmt
[mgmt]# info
(information obtained)
[mgmt]# select hci0
Selected index 0
[hci0]# discov no
[hci0]# exit
```

If the name of the device that you get is different from `hci0` you should use that.
You can check with `# info` (under `current settings`) that the change took place.

The same can be achieved with

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 pscan
```

Check with

```
hciconfig -a
```

that you have `UP RUNNING PSCAN`, without `ISCAN` (inquiry scan).

If persistence of the setting is a problem, you could add a cron job that runs on boot.